# Use router as wireless to wireless instead of wired to wireless. (connect router to wifi)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

I want to use my router to connect to a public wifi and then use that internet to broadcast its own wifi. Example: connect to "public" and send out "mywifi". I know windows uses Internet Connection Sharing to accomplish this but can routers. router are used for wired to wireless connections but can one be used for wireless to wireless?

Comment: Perhaps you describing a wireless repeater.

Comment: You will often need either two routers or a router and an access point. Most routers can only operate one WiFi network on one channel. I have had nothing but bad luck with wireless repeaters and do not recommend them unless they do real NAT and are, in effect, an access point connected to a masquerading router.